# CSS cube wobbling when rotating

Tags: css

Trying to make a cube that spins but it wobbles up and down when it rotates think its got something to do with transform origin. Tried messing around with different values for the cube but it only becomes more exaggerated.

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@keyframes spin-vertical
{
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg); }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@-webkit-keyframes spin-vertical
{
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg); }
}

body
{
    font: normal 30px "HelveticaNeue-Light", sans-serif;
}

.wrapper
{
    margin: 200px;
    background-color: black;
}

.face
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}

.cube
{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-animation: spin-vertical 5s infinite linear;
    -moz-transform-origin: 10px 18px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 10px 18px;
    -o-transform-origin: 10px 18px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 10px 18px;
    transform-origin: 10px 18px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#top
{
    -moz-transform: rotatex(-270deg) translatey(-40px);
    -ms-transform: rotatex(-270deg) translatey(-40px);
    -o-transform: rotatex(-270deg) translatey(-40px);
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-270deg) translatey(-40px);
    transform: rotatex(-270deg) translatey(-40px);
    -moz-transform-origin: top center;
    -ms-transform-origin: top center;
    -o-transform-origin: top center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center
}

#bottom
{
    -moz-transform: rotatex(90deg) translatey(0);
    -ms-transform: rotatex(90deg) translatey(0);
    -o-transform: rotatex(90deg) translatey(0);
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(90deg) translatey(0);
    transform: rotatex(90deg) translatey(0);
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom center;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform-origin: bottom center
}

#back
{
    -moz-transform: translatez(-40px) rotatex(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: translatez(-40px) rotatex(-180deg);
    -o-transform: translatez(-40px) rotatex(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: translatez(-40px) rotatex(-180deg);
    transform: translatez(-40px) rotatex(-180deg)
}

#front
{
    -moz-transform: translatez(40px);
    -ms-transform: translatez(40px);
    -o-transform: translatez(40px);
    -webkit-transform: translatez(40px);
    transform: translatez(40px)
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="cube" id="cuberotate">
            <div class="face" id="front">FACE 1</div>
            <div class="face" id="top">FACE 4</div>
            <div class="face" id="bottom">FACE 2</div>
            <div class="face" id="back">FACE 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w1kc28zp/**

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Done some updates to how the sides are transformed, also you're right about transform-origin. On the cube element it should be "0 20px" where 20px stands for 50% of the height of each side.

See result at: https://jsfiddle.net/w1kc28zp/1/

```
.cube {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin:0 20px;
  -webkit-animation: spin-vertical 5s infinite linear;
}

#front {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(20px); 
}
#top {
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) translateY(-20px);
  transform-origin:top center;
}
#back {
  transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(180deg);
}
#bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(20px);
  transform-origin:bottom center;
}
```